# Console Application Not working in Windows Shared Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-server-2008

We have developed a console application and its working on our local machine without any issue.

Now we have build the solution and placed the "Release" folder in a shared server, it should run by a scheduled job and we gave high privileges to that account also.

In the solution, we have the main function in Program.cs file and in that we are calling another class file. Up to the main function its working fine but when it tries to call that particular function in another call file, console closing without any message.

But when we run the solution by accessing the shared path it's working without any issue. I am struggling a lot but no luck.

Please help me to get a breakthrough.

Comment: I guess it's permission problem.

Comment: But its running up to main function but not the particular class file or particular method..

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: No.. Any issue with .Net framework?